# PHP - can't logout user using $_SESSION global

Tags: php, session, authentication

I've been stuck on this for more than a day, and I hope someone here can help me out. I know I'm not the first one to ask questions about logging in/out with sessions in PHP, but other answers I found never seemed to work for me.

At the moment I'm doing the server-side scripting for a website my colleagues and I are making. The website is supposed to have an admin dashboard where the admin can see some nice data, which is off-limit to other visitors of the website. Therefore I'm attempting to build a login/logout system using sessions, the first time I've done so since I started web development.

The problem is that, while logging in seems to work fine, logging out is not working at all. No matter what I try, the $_SESSION['user'] never is destroyed and always remains equal to the admin username. Does anybody here know what I'm doing wrong?

I'll be posting my login.php, logout.php and the jQuery ajax functions I'm using to call these. In case it's important for answering the question: the website currently leads all routes to index.php, where different views are shown depending on the route.

Help would be much appreciated!

***login.php***

```
session_start();
if ($_POST) {
    $nameInput = $_POST['usernameLogin'];
    $passwordInput = $_POST['passwordLogin'];
    $DBrow = dbCompare("adminDash", "user", $nameInput);
    if ($DBrow != NULL) {
        $hashPass = $DBrow['pass'];
        $passCheck = password_verify($passwordInput, $hashPass);
        if ($passCheck == TRUE) {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $DBrow['user'];
            header("Location: ./dashboard");
        }  
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

***logout.php***

```
session_start();
if ($_POST) {
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
    session_destroy();

    if(session_destroy()) {
        header("Location: ./");
    }
}
```

***jQuery Ajax calls***

```
function logIn() {
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        usernameLogin: document.getElementById("usernameLogin").value,
        passwordLogin: document.getElementById("passwordLogin").value
    },
    url: '/app/dataAccess/login.php',
    success: function(response){
        if (response == 0)    {
            alert("Uw gebruikersnaam en/of wachtoord komen niet overeen. Probeer het nog een keer of herstel uw wachtwoord met onderstaande knop.")
        }
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("Er ging iets mis met het verzenden van uw data. Neem contact op met uw systeembeheerder.")
    }
})
}

function logOut() {
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/app/dataAccess/logout.php',
    success: function (response) {
        alert("succes")
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("error")
    }
  })
}
```

***Bootstrap modal used for logging in/out***

```
<div class="modal backgroundPijl form-horizontal text-center" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <!-- Modal Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="col-12 modal-title text-center">Admin login</h5>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal body -->
    <?php if ($_SESSION['user']) : ?> 
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a type="button" id="loginButton" class="btn btn-danger mr-auto" onclick="logOut()" href="/home">Logout</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
    <?php else : ?>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="usernameLogin">Gebruikersnaam</label>
            <input id="usernameLogin" name="usernameLogin" class="form-control">  
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="passwordLogin">Wachtwoord</label>
            <input id="passwordLogin" type="password" name="passwordLogin" class="form-control">  
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal footer -->
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="loginButton" class="btn btn-danger mr-auto" onclick="validateLogin()" href="/dashboard">Login</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mr-auto ml-auto">Wachtwoord vergeten?</button>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your second  session_destroy() in then if()...  will run into false, cause the first one destroys it

Comment: thanks for your comment Freddy, but removing the second session destroy in the if statement didn't seem to change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with another solution

write below code in `logout.php` and its worked.

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['user']); 
exit();
```